# C++ select function breaks prematurely

Tags: c++, sockets

Okay, first off: Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't figure out the correct keywords if it had been.

Situation: I have a small Network server, which runs in it's own Thread. The 'Run'-Method iterates over a collection of active Sockets (Both UDP and TCP), checks for Activity and does it's thing. All of this is achieved via `select`.

It is possible, that, while 'stuck' in `select` a new server is added. For this purpose, I have incorporated a 'Breaker socket', which is checked alongside the others. It gets closed when a new socket is added, so the new socket will also be monitored for traffic. (fd_set gets regenerated each time select got broken)

Code is like this (abbreviated):

```
fd_set fds;
SOCKET mSock = Breaker;

FD_ZERO(&fds);
//Aquire Mutex
if(Breaker == INVALID_SOCKET)
    mSock = Breaker = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
FD_SET(Breaker, &fds);
//Iterate over active sockets and add them to fds.
//Release Mutex

if(select(mSock + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) > 0) {
    //AquireMutex
    //Iterate over active sockets, check for activity and act accordingly.
    if(Breaker != INVALID_SOCKET && FD_ISSET(Breaker, &fds)
        //Close Breaker and set it to INVALID_SOCKET
    //Release Mutex
}
```

Now the actual problem: `select` is broken continuously, no matter whether I close Breaker or not. It constantly reports 'activity' on the socket.

Breaker is a simple socket, not bound or connected.
If I change the type of Breaker to 'DGRAM', it doesn't break select at all, even if closed.

Language is C++, Platform is a Linux-derivate, INVALID_SOCKET is defined as -1 and SOCKET is a typedef to int. (Code is supposed to work with WinSock too)

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
I've tried reading from the Buffer. Calling `recv` on the Breaker socket returned with -1, setting `errno` to 107 (Transport endpoint not connected), which is not surprising, seeing how it really isn't connected.

Edit:
Since my intention apparently is unclear, I'll describe it again.
It is possible, that a new server socket is added to the queue at any given point in time. However this socket will not be monitored for traffic, unless select is broken (and fd_set is subsequently refilled with the new socket) at least once. Any traffic arriving on the new socket is thereby discarded.

I am aware, that I could be using timeouts, but I was hoping there'd be a different solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Nothing you are saying is surprising except that you're surprised by this behavior.

Comment: With TCP connection you could select the listener socket to wait for new incoming connections.

Comment: @PatrickB. Yes, quite so. However the problem arises, if a new listener is added to the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a socket to signal an event you could use a pipe (`man 2 pipe`).

I'd rather revise your architecture if possible.

PS: I swear I haven't looked on the question proposed by Michael Burr in a comment.

Comment: Haha, yeah well, the result is important, not who it came from. I'll check it out immediately.

Comment: Using a pipe to allow a `select()` to be interrupted is also discussed in Steven's "Unix Network Programming, Vol 1" 3rd Ed. (Section 20.5).  I think it's a relatively common technique that should be better known.

Answer (score 7):

This is expected. If there's nothing to wait for, `select` cannot wait. If the socket is closed, there's nothing to wait for. If the socket isn't connected, there's nothing to wait for. If you want `select` to wait, you have to give it something to wait for. And when it tells you that there's nothing to wait for, you shouldn't ask it to wait again -- that makes no sense. You have to handle whatever `select` is telling you before you call it again or the same thing will just keep happening.

Comment: Okay, and how would I make this scenario work then? What I want is to simply close the socket (or do whatever) to get select to break and refill the fd_set.

Comment: I don't follow. If you want to close the socket, call `close`. If you want `select` to break, then arrange it to break when the condition you want occurs. Are you trying to close a socket in one thread while another thread is using it? (That won't work.) Or what? You haven't described your problem well.

Comment: First off: Thanks for helping me. Second: I want to be able to break select at any given point in time, so it'll refill the variable 'fd_set' with updated data (additional socket to listen on). If there is an easier way than closing a socket, I haven't found it yet.

Comment: @ATaylor: see if this SO question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486727/breaking-out-from-socket-select

Comment: @ATaylor From another thread? Closing the socket *will not work*, do not do that. You can, however, `shutdown` the socket and then `close` it later, when you're sure no other thread is, or might be, using it.

Comment: If necessary, you can also `select` on a pipe and write a dummy byte to it just to unblock `select`. (Don't forget to read from the pipe to "re-arm" it.)

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks for heads up, I'm looking at it now.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yeah, I kinda realized that it won't work (besides, I'm using shutdown and close on the socket to close it, but that's besides the point). I'll take a look at the pipe-idea.

Comment: @ATaylor Make sure you do not `close` it until you are 100% certain that no other thread is, or could be, using it in any way or very bad things will happen.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Understood. My architecture is devised so the actual Socket variable is set to INVALID_SOCKET before executing `close`. The thread which would use it will check for INVALID_SOCKET before trying anything else, as such I should be safe.

Comment: @ATaylor That won't work. Please, don't do that. Suppose the thread has already set the socket in the FD_SET but has not called `select` yet and you close the socket. You now have a potentially catastrophic race condition. Use `shutdown`, and do not call `close` until you know that no other thread is, or could be, using the socket.